# CSRF Failure On AJAX POST Request After Deploy Django Application With Nginx

Tags: ajax, django, nginx, csrf, django-csrf

I use Nginx and Gunicorn to deploy my Django 2.X blog on VPS.
When i push some data to Django backend via Jquery AJAX, then i got 403 CSRF error. I googled a lot but still can't figure out how to fix this problem. **I tried to deploy them on my local computer with same configuration files, and everything is okay**.

Firstly, I didn't set `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True` and `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True` in my Django `settings.py` . so they are both default value `False`.

I've copied the AJAX sample code from [Django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#ajax):

```
// get csrftoken via JavaScript
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        let cookies = document.cookie.split(';')
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            let cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i])
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1))
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue
}

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method))
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: (xhr, settings) => {
        let $captchaMassage = $('#captcha-message')
        let csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken')
        console.debug('csrftoken: ' + csrftoken)
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
        }
        if ($captchaMassage) {
            $captchaMassage.text('please wait...')
        }
    }
})
```

and this is my AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        async: true,
        method: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "captcha_mine_taken_verification" %}',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'coinhive_captcha_token': token},
        success: result => {
            if (result.success) {
                console.debug(result.data)
                $captchaMassage.text('thanks to donate')
            } else {
                $captchaMassage.text('failure reason: ' + result.reason)
            }
        },
        error: () => {
            $captchaMassage.text('oh my god, something wrong...')
        }
    })
```

this is Request Header from Chrome:

```
POST /cloudsen_blog/captcha-mine/taken-verification HTTP/1.1
Host: 104.243.15.163
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 55
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://104.243.15.163
X-CSRFToken: null           <<<< this always null
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://104.243.15.163/cloudsen_blog/blog/article/5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6
```

this is my Gunicorn config file:

```
import multiprocessing

# unix domain socket
# bind = 'unix:/home/cloudsen/work/deploy/webservers/sockets/nginx-gunicorn.sock'
# TCP
bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
worker_class = 'gevent'
errorlog = '/home/cloudsen/work/deploy/webservers/gunicorn/gunicorn.error.log'
accesslog = '/home/cloudsen/work/deploy/webservers/gunicorn/gunicorn.access.log'
proc_name = 'gunicorn_myblog'
```

this is my Nginx config file:

```
worker_processes 2;
user cloudsen;
error_log /home/cloudsen/work/deploy/webservers/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    accept_mutex on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile off;
    access_log /home/cloudsen/work/deploy/webservers/nginx/access.log combined;
    # Arch Linux start
    types_hash_max_size 4096;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    # Arch Linux end

    upstream app_server {
        #server unix:/home/cloudsen/work/deploy/webservers/sockets/nginx-gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
        server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        return 444;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 104.243.15.163;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location /favicon.ico {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /home/cloudsen/work/python/project/RedQueen/collected_statics/;
        }

        location = / {
            rewrite ^ /cloudsen_blog;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass_header X-CSRFToken;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }
    }
}
```

What's more, when i debug in Chrome, I found that my AJAX didn't send CSRF-TOKEN, and `document.cookie` always get empty string, so `getCookie('csrftoken')` always return Null. But i don't know why.

Thanks for help ~~~

Comment: You haven't shown what your CSRF settings are, but perhaps the section [*acquiring the token if CSRF_USE_SESSIONS or CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY is True*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-or-csrf-cookie-httponly-is-true) is what you need.

Comment: thx dude, i didn't set `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True` and `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True` in my Django settings.py . so they are both default value `False`, i think js cookie should be work.

Comment: Use your browser tools to check if the cookie has been set. Have you visited a url that sets the cookie before making the ajax request. Perhaps you need to use the `ensure_csrf_cookie()` decorator.

Comment: Oh, this is so nice dude. I have tried this decorator, and it works well～～Indeed, this is mentioned in the documentation, but I did not pay attention to it.

Comment: I think that's strange, by default Django always sets a CSRF cookie on every request if you've added 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' to your `MIDDLEWARE` settings. You shouldn't have to explicitly decorate a view.

Comment: yep,  Alasdair helped me solved this problem, but i still don't know why.

Comment: @dirkgroten I don't think the middleware sets the cookie on every request. From the [how it works](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#how-it-works) docs: *This cookie is set by CsrfViewMiddleware. It is sent with every response that has called django.middleware.csrf.get_token()*. Usually, the GET request to view the form ensures the cookie is set, and then the POST request works. For ajax, you need to ensure that the cookie has been set.

Answer (score 0):

> Page uses AJAX without any HTML form¶
>   A page makes a POST request via AJAX, and the page does not have an HTML form with a csrf_token that would cause the required CSRF cookie to be sent.

Solution: use ensure_csrf_cookie() on the view that sends the page.
By use `ensure_csrf_cookie()` decorator finally solved the problem.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

# use this on your view
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def go_article_detail_page(request: HttpRequest, article_pk: int):
    pass
```

And now, whenever you visit the page, Django will send a `csrftoken` in `document.cookie` .